# Figuring out why Foobar2000 takes forever to launch in Wine

Tags: linux, wine, foobar2000

Whenever I try to launch Foobar2000, it takes very long, around 15 seconds. I created a log from the Wine command line debug output, and the vast majority of the time seems to be taken up by operations that produce log entries that look like this:

```
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\d2d1.dll" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\user-components\\foo_jscript_panel3\\d2d1.dll" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\d3d10_1.dll" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\user-components\\foo_jscript_panel3\\d3d10_1.dll" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\d3d10core.dll" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\user-components\\foo_jscript_panel3\\d3d10core.dll" not found (c0000034)
...
```

```
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\C:\\windows\\fonts\\coure.fon" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\C:\\windows\\fonts\\coure.fon" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"C:\\windows\\fonts\\coure.fon" (status c0000034)
0024:warn:dwrite_file:create_local_cached_stream Failed to open the file L"C:\\windows\\fonts\\coure.fon", error 2.
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\C:\\windows\\fonts\\sserife.fon" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\C:\\windows\\fonts\\sserife.fon" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"C:\\windows\\fonts\\sserife.fon" (status c0000034)
0024:warn:dwrite_file:create_local_cached_stream Failed to open the file L"C:\\windows\\fonts\\sserife.fon", error 2.
...
```

```
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\metadb.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\metadb.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
...
```

```
0024:warn:file:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\configuration\\Core.cfg" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\configuration\\foo_cad.dll.cfg" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\configuration\\foo_converter.dll.cfg" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\configuration\\foo_convolve.dll.cfg" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\configuration\\foo_dsp_eq.dll.cfg" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\configuration\\foo_dsp_std.dll.cfg" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\configuration\\foo_dsp_xgeq.dll.cfg" not found (c0000034)
...
```

```
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-journal" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtQueryFullAttributesFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\.foobar2000\\profile\\config.sqlite-wal" not found (c0000034)
...
```

```
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\linux-gate.so.1" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"linux-gate.so.1" (status c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\i386-windows\\linux-gate.so.1" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\i386-windows\\linux-gate.so.1" (status c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\linux-gate.so.1" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\linux-gate.so.1" (status c0000034)
0024:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
0024:warn:dbghelp:module_is_container_loaded Couldn't find container for L"C:\\windows\\system32\\d2d1.dll"
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\home\\lutra\\linux-gate.so.1" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"linux-gate.so.1" (status c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\i386-windows\\linux-gate.so.1" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\i386-windows\\linux-gate.so.1" (status c0000034)
0024:warn:file:NtCreateFile L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\linux-gate.so.1" not found (c0000034)
0024:warn:file:CreateFileW Unable to create file L"\\??\\Z:\\usr\\lib32\\wine\\linux-gate.so.1" (status c0000034)
0024:fixme:dbghelp:elf_search_auxv can't find symbol in module
...
```

Etc. There are over 3000 of these warn:file messages, and yet Foobar2000 runs fine once it actually launches. How can I prevent these operations from slowing down the launch?